# OBJ file - how to identify object?

Tags: android-studio, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry, google-project-tango

I have an `*.obj` file that rapresented a chair with other stuff that I don't care. How can my Project Tango/Android smartphone/whatever identify the "most important" object in that file?

The most important is in the middle of the record...

Comment: That would depend on whats "The most important" object. The question makes no sense. I guess you could look at this? 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_single-object_recognition

Comment: group points that are connected to each other by a face. That should segmentate all the objects after that select the biggest one (either by size or number of faces ... depends on the content and task you are doing which we can not know ... without more info or sample example)

Comment: For example: I need to scan a wardrobe all around it. I can scan it with my Project Tango and after that I have an obj file of it. In the obj file I have the wardrobe and also the floor and maybe a window. I want to remove the floor and window and focus on the wardrobe. Is more clear now?

Comment: ¨Spektre has a point but I think that would remove the object since it will never be "complete" or atleast almost never. Taking the biggest one would take a wall in many cases.

Comment: I know that and I want to find an algorithm that can identify the object with a group of point cloud that is very close to a real object.

Comment: without at least image of possible scenes is hard to help. If you got background and floor then yes biggest object will not be the one... you can detect object centered  in view, ... or detect/remove floor (large flat area) or get the object names from obj (if present) and use their names to filter out ... etc but without actual samples is all just guess work

Comment: Also another way to identify object is by its use of materials. As a last resort do a manual selection (for example by a mouse wheel looping through all of the objects)

Comment: @Spektre thank you very  much. I didn't think about that